# Matlab Recursive Loop

Tags: matlab, loops, categorical-data

I have a cell that contain cells of different unique values of categorical variables. Let's say the cell is called r, in r{1,1}, we have the 1st category which includes "a","b", "c", in r{1,2} we have "high","low", and so on to r{1,n}.

My question is how to do I make a loop to get all possible combinations of the categorical combinations. I am unable to use allcombs function because each cell within r must be entered separately. I need to make this loop inside of a larger function.

Comment: stick the entire cell array into one cell and make a recursive function that loops and calls itself on each cell then you can call that function on your outermost cell.

Comment: For the record this site is not a code writing service, if you don't know the language then find an online tutorial or something. In the future you need to include a code sample and we can help you fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code into myFunc.m and call myFunc on your cell array that is nested with other cell arrays.

```
function myFunc(cellArray)

    %Do some stuff

    [I,J] = size(cellArray);
    %if they are both 1 then you know to stop the recursion
    if(I>1 || J > 1)
        for i = 1:I
            for j = 1:J
                myFunc(cellArray{i,j})
            end
        end
    end
end
```